# Sorting values of a dictionary based on a list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort the values of a dictionary (which are lists) based on one of the lists. For example say I have the dictionary:

```
data = {'AttrA':[2,4,1,3],'AttrB':[12,43,23,25],'AttrC':['a','d','f','z']}
```

and I would like to sort this based on the values associated with AttrA, such that:

```
data = {'AttrA':[1,2,3,4],'AttrB':[23,12,25,43],'AttrC':['f','a','z','d']}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simplify the question. It's has nothing to do with dictionaries, but rather is "How can I sort a list and then map other lists based on the sorted positions?" (Or, perhaps "How can I sort a list based on another list?")

Comment: sort first list, create a list of indices from it; apply indices to remaining lists.  You probably have to make copies of lists unless you are clever.

Comment: Question is simple enough.

Comment: Apply the dupe question solution to *each* value in your dictionary, using the `AttrA` value as the 'input' list.

Comment: I see the point, but sometimes when people 'simplify' questions, they leave out a salient point or typo that is very germane to solving the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort each value in your dictionary based on the `data['AttrA']` source list, using `sorted()` and `zip()`, all in just 3 lines of code:

```
base = data['AttrA'] # keep a reference to the original sort order
for key in data:
    data[key] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(base, data[key]))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = {'AttrA': [2, 4, 1, 3], 'AttrB': [12, 43, 23, 25], 'AttrC': ['a', 'd', 'f', 'z']}
>>> base = data['AttrA']
>>> for key in data:
...     data[key] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(base, data[key]))]
... 
>>> data
{'AttrB': [23, 12, 25, 43], 'AttrC': ['f', 'a', 'z', 'd'], 'AttrA': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: That is elegant... so elegant

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = {'AttrA':[2,4,1,3],'AttrB':[12,43,23,25],'AttrC':['a','d','f','z']}

sort = itemgetter(*[i for i, v in sorted(enumerate(data['AttrA']), key=itemgetter(1))])
data = dict((k, list(sort(v))) for k, v in data.items())
```

Or a shorter but less efficient method of creating `sort`:

```
sort = itemgetter(*[data['AttrA'].index(v) for v in sorted(data['AttrA'])])
```

Result:

```
>>> data
{'AttrB': [23, 12, 25, 43], 'AttrC': ['f', 'a', 'z', 'd'], 'AttrA': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

This uses [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a sorting function that grabs items from a sequence in the order determined by `data['AttrA']`, and then applying that sorting function to each value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work (or at least be a good place to start)

```
data = {'AttrA':[2,4,1,3],'AttrB':[12,43,23,25],'AttrC':['a','d','f','z']}
sortkey = 'AttrA'
sortedval = sorted(data['AttrA'])
valmaps = {i:sortedvals.find(num) for i,num in enumerate(data['AttrA'])}
newData = {k:[v[valmaps[i]] for i,_num in enumerate(v)] for k,v in data.items()}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will fail if `data['AttrA']` contains non-unique values, but the other lists do. `'AttrA': [2, 4, 1, 4]` means your `valmaps` dictionary will have have `1` and `3` map to `3`..

Comment: True! I hadn't considered that